# Jquery show button after 5 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got this button that I need to show after 5 second. I have no experience in jquery or javascript

HTML Code

```
<body>
<p>You need to wait 0 before you can proceed</p>
<button type="button" id="proceed">proceed</button>
</body>
```

This is the best that I could come up with after some reading in w3school

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#show").wait(function(){
  delay 0500  $("proceed").show();
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have no div there.. what is it you want to show in 5 seconds? The button? The paragraph? Everything?

Comment: the button or maybe some extra the timer change 5 to 0 then show the button

Comment: What is `#show`? Is that something the user should click on to start the timer?

Comment: Barmar Its something I pick up on w3school. I have no idea what Im doing

Comment: take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eGWx9/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery, then use the setTimeOut method as answered by others.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#proceed').delay(5000).show(0);   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>You need to wait 0 before you can proceed</p>
<button type="button" id="proceed" style="display: none;">proceed</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Should the first `show()` be `hide()`?

Comment: how can I implement that in my code?

Comment: `show(0).delay(5000).show(0)`???

Comment: doesnt seem to work with this `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Proceed</button>`

Comment: can you elaborate as to what isn't working?  also, it would be best in a real world case to select the button by its id, or class or pretty much anything other than button.  i'll update

Answer (score 7):

Use `setTimeout()` to run a function after a time delay:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#proceed").show();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
#proceed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>You need to wait 0 before you can proceed</p>
<button type="button" id="proceed">proceed</button>
```

Comment: How do I do this with bootstrap button?

Comment: or `$("#proceed").delay(5000).show(0);`

Comment: @aviva What's the bootstrap button? I don't see anything like that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display timer `setInterval` can be used.

```js
var i = 4;
var time = $("#time")
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  time.html(i);
  if (i == 0) {
    $("#proceed").show();
    clearInterval(timer);

  }
  i--;
}, 1000)
```

```css
#proceed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>You need to wait <span id="time">5</span> before you can proceed</p>
<button type="button" id="proceed">proceed</button>
```

Comment: Sorry updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to postpone a function is:

```
    setTimeOut(function(){
         //put your code here.
    },5000)//5000 millisecond
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out. `.hide()` will hide the button after the page loads. `.delay(5000)` will wait 5000 milliseconds. Then `.show(0)` will run after that, showing the button.

```
$('#proceed').hide().delay(5000).show(0);
```

Comment: `Then .show() will run after that, showing the button` no it won't be put in fx queue, you need to animate it in some way, easiest one would be to pass some duration to `show()` method, e.g: `$('#proceed').hide().delay(5000).show(0);`

Comment: is it possible to use this with bootstrap without changing the css?

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

You have no div section in your code.

```
<div id="showing"></div>

setTimeout(function(){
   $('#showing').show();
}, 5000);`
```

The above example is showing a div section after 5 seconds delays

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `setTimeout` method this way.
Below is a working example. A `div` will appear 5 seconds after the **Run Code Snippet**
 is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('div').css('display','block');
     }, 5000);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```