# Disappears after passing a certain time

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just a p of CSS I want to disappear after a while I looked here and found this, but the opposite instead of hiding appears https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751324/10634372

Comment: Just change `.show()` to `.hide()`.

Comment: What is your actual question? Please include any code relevant to the question, in the question itself. What is "just a p of CSS"?

Comment: as Jon P says, it really is quite unclear what you are asking. Linking to other questions or external code will put a lot of people off investigating your problem. Please describe clearly what you would like to do and show what you have already tried.

Comment: I just wanted the opposite way of this code - .show to hide https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751324/10634372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code on the other stack overflow answer where the code says `$("#proceed").show();`
remove the `.show();` and replace it with `.hide();`

the full code would be:

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<p>You have <span id="time">5</span> seconds to proceed</p>
<button type="button" id="proceed">proceed</button>
```

```
var i = 4;
var time = $("#time")
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  time.html(i);
  if (i == 0) {
    $("#proceed").hide();
    clearInterval(timer);

  }
  i--;
}, 1000)
```

```
#proceed {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Did not succeed, they disappear immediately, must disappear after 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You may dispense with JavaScript's setTimeout() as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#proceed").show();
  });

$("button").click(function(){
  $("#wait").hide("slow");
  $(this).fadeOut("slow");

  $("#welcome")
.delay(500)
  .queue(function (next) { 
$(this).fadeIn(); 
$(this).animate({"font-size":"56pt","letter-spacing":".3em"},"fast");
next(); 
  });

});
```

```css
#proceed {
      display: none;
}

#wait {
font: 1em Arial,Helvetica;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

 #welcome {
 display:none;
 color:red;
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica;
 text-shadow: 3px 4px #999;
 }
 
 span {
 margin:0;
 }
 
 button {
 margin-left:45%;
 }

 p {
   background-color:beige;
   text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><span id="wait">You need to wait 0 before you can proceed.</span>  
<span  id="welcome">Welcome</span></p>
<button type="button" id="proceed">proceed</button>
```

jQuery provides HTML elements different methods governing their display, such as .hide(), .show(), .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() and each of these can take a string parameter such as "slow" or "fast" or else a number to specify the duraction of the effect.

When it comes to how fast a CSS property is set, there is also something else available, namely a [queue function](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) whose execution you may [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/). That portion of this example's code derives from an answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396158/701302). However, note the following:

> "The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. —.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases."

Source: [here](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

The animate() method can also affect how slow or fast an element displays.